# How to pass a parameter to a CSS class using LESS?

Tags: css, less

Not sure if this is possible using LESS, but I saw `.rotate(@degrees) {...}` (is that only work in LESS)

I want to be able to write one CSS class and pass the number as a parameter from the HTML - for example: `<div class="opacity(20)">`

Here is just an example of a repeated CSS class that I use (but even passing an integer will be great):

```css
.opacity-10 {
  opacity: 0.1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)"; // IE 8
  filter: alpha(opacity=10); // IE 5-7
  -moz-opacity: 0.1; // Netscape
  -khtml-opacity: 0.1; // Safari 1.x
}
.opacity-20 {
  opacity: 0.2;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)"; // IE 8
  filter: alpha(opacity=20); // IE 5-7
  -moz-opacity: 0.2; // Netscape
  -khtml-opacity: 0.2; // Safari 1.x
}

// ...
```

Comment: You can create a LESS mixin that uses a parameter, but you cannot use parameters in the CSS. That is, you cannot do something like `<div class="opacity(20)">` unless you have defined a class named `.opacity(20)`.

Comment: this is not possible with css.  also ie 5- 7? these browsers are dead and no longer supported by microsoft

Comment: Maybe I can use jQuery to modify specific class names on the fly, but I was looking for a better way...

Comment: Duplicate of [Can less.js read class names and parameters from HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104746/can-less-js-read-class-names-and-parameters-from-html)